# Why do games keep crashing on my phone?

Tags: crashes

I have Samsung Galaxy Ace. I'm installing apps from Google Play or just download them on my PC and then transfere them with Bluetooth. Now my problem is that some games crash or be white on some spots, for example there is main menu and play, and thay play is a just white square and it starts the app so it is just a graphical bug. But game like Blood Zombies HD just keeps crashing with report/force close. I have lot of free memory on my phone and on SD card and my phone had needed requierements and no backround apps running. And like a half of games on Google Play have same force close/report thing. So please answere me to fix this problem

Comment: Is this a new phone? Sounds like you might need to take it back to the shop.

Comment: Is it a custom rom with all dexed/deodexed apks?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say this, but the Samsung Galaxy ace has a lower end processor as well as a small amount of ram. Although your device meets the requirements, its specifications don't allow it to run well. Games like blood zombies HD require higher performing devices with a satisfactory GPU. Your phone cannot handle games like these.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with Solar.
Generally a simple game like 2048,Smash it do not require any Graphics processor to process the game so it runs very smoothly.

Whereas high end games like Asaphalt 8 ,FIFA 2014,Blood Zombies hd require some serious graphics to be processed during the game play. Although some times the game may even start but later your phone will not be able to process the graphics with just 200 MB of RAM and no GPU on board the device. Your game is starting only because you are having high processing speed i.e.1.2GHz

If you want to play Blood Zombies HD you need to have the following

1)1.2 Ghz processor to run the game smoothly(Single core ok but quad core would be good)

2)Hd screen with 720x1280 screen resolution.(if at all you really want hd or else you can ignore)

3)GPU Adreno 305 or any other processor from other company like Nvidia.(As your phone has a separate graphics card it will handle all your games with ease)

4)2000 mAh battery to last the phone for 1 day (if it's less ok but your game itself will consume the whole battery)

5)Good touch screen (or else you will end up where touch will not respond to your input during the game)

6)Last but not the least 2-3 GB on board storage space(The os will occupy around 500 MB -1Gb storage space and you will not only play 1 game or use a single application you must have some space for other apps as well)

Note:-With present phone you cannot do that level of game which you want to play. If you want then go for another phone with the above features(based on the region /country you could many budget phones).

Answer (score -1):

Scroll up on the top right corner click the manage apps button and then click clear then press on setting disable all the useless app, restar your phone and then you are ready to go

Comment: This is essentially just a troubleshooting step. Please keep troubleshooting to comments. If you stick around around on the site and participate, you'll very soon have the reputation necessary to comment on posts.